# Android: How to get SharedPreferences of an object dynamically?

Tags: android, dynamic, sharedpreferences

I have an Array with the IDs of several checkboxes. In `onResume` I wish to check whether the booleans of those checkboxes are `true` or `false` (using a loop) in order to adapt the view. Here is my Code. It does not work as it tells me that every value is `false`. Could someone tell me why this is happening?

```
ArrayList<Integer> boxArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
boxArray.add(R.id.boxA);
boxArray.add(R.id.boxB);
boxArray.add(R.id.boxC);
```

And in `onReturn`:

```
SharedPreferences preferences =
  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

for (int i=0; i<boxArray.size(); i++) {
  if (preferences.getBoolean
      (findViewById(boxArray.get(i)).toString(), false) == true) {
    //change the view of the checkbox to checked if its value is true
    CheckBox currentBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(boxArray.get(i));
    currentBox.setChecked(true);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you set the value in shared preferences?

When a box is checked do you do something like

```
preferences.edit().putBoolean(TheCheckedBoxId, true);
```

If the shared preference getBoolean() method is always defaulting to false then either the value is not there at all or it is just false. I think you can try

```
preferences.contains(findViewById(boxArray.get(i)).toString())
```

to see if that key exists at all. There's also the preferences.getAll() method.